# Having a table and a picture on top of the title

Tags: tables, graphics, titles

I am trying to put a logo and also a table before a document title. When I add a title, it adds to number of pages and starts the actual document from the next page. I was wondering if there is a way to fix this problem.

Thank you,

I apologize if my MWE is too long, I did not remove any of the packages cause I thought it might have something to do with the packages I use. Thank you

```
\documentclass[12pt, xcolor=pdftex,x11names,table]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{multicol}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage[compact,small]{titlesec}
\usepackage[titles,subfigure]{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{comment}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}

\geometry{left=25mm,right=20mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm}
\geometry{letterpaper} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\clubpenalty = 10000
\widowpenalty = 10000
\onehalfspacing 
\setlength{\parskip}{0ex}

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\lhead{I}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{H}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\hypersetup{ 
pdftitle={F}, 
pdfauthor={G},
bookmarks=true, bookmarksopen=true, pdftoolbar=true, 
pdffitwindow=false,
colorlinks=false,
linkcolor=red, 
citecolor=red,
filecolor=magenta,
urlcolor=black }
%\input{tcilatex}
\title{Test}
\date{}
\begin{document}


\hspace*{-0.35in}%
\begin{tabular}{l}
{%
\includegraphics[
natheight=1.042100in,
natwidth=2.989700in,
height=1.0758in,
]{logo.eps}}%
\end{tabular}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\quad 
\begin{tabular}{r}
\emph{A} \\ 
\emph{B} \\ 
\emph{C} \\ 
\emph{D}%
\end{tabular}
\title{Test Title}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really think _any_ of those package are related to the question, please make a _minimal_ example that focusses on the problem that you are asking about, also use demo option or replace includegraphics by a rule so people have a chance of running it locally

Comment: _you_ can test whether the packages are relevant. Just delete packages and if the problem you have is still there leave them out, if removing a package makes the problem come back, that is useful fact that you can include in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use  `background` or `tikz` (with `remember picture` and `overlay`) for this:

An example with `tikz`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Test}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node at ($(current page.north west) +(2,-2)$)
{\includegraphics[
width=1in
]{example-image-a}};%
\node at ($(current page.north east) +(-2,-2)$)
{\begin{tabular}{r}
\emph{A} \\
\emph{B} \\
\emph{C} \\
\emph{D}%
\end{tabular}};
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The `\maketitle` command issues a `\newpage` to ensure that the title appears on the top of a fresh page; somebody may want to have a cover page before it.

So our job is to put the material *after* this `\newpage`, which is easy with `etoolbox`, rather than copying and pasting the complete definition from `article.cls` and modifying it. The command to patch is actually `\@maketitle`, that does the typesetting job.

Note that this is just for `article.cls` and is not guaranteed to work with other classes.

It's also better to store the material in a command, so as to minimize the patching job. Modify at will the amount of negative vertical spacing.

IMPORTANT NOTE: the `demo` option to `graphicx` is just for demonstration purpose, don't use it yourself. The only package you need to load (as you already load `graphicx`) is `etoolbox`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\beforetitle}{%
  \vspace*{-6\baselineskip}
  \noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    \includegraphics[natheight=1.042100in,
      natwidth=2.989700in,height=1.0758in,]{logo.eps}
  \end{tabular}%
  \hspace{10em}%
  \begin{tabular}{r}
  \emph{A} \\ 
  \emph{B} \\ 
  \emph{C} \\ 
  \emph{D}
  \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}\par
}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}
  {\newpage\null}
  {\newpage\beforetitle}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Test Title}
\author{A. U. Thor}
\date{}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Notes about your preamble:

- the options `xcolor=pdftex,x11names,table` don't make sense with the `article` class; you should do

  ```
  \usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor}
  ```
- loading both `sectsty` and `titlesec` is wrong; use only one of them.
- Passing the option `pdftex` to any package is in general wrong.
- `\usepackage{type1cm}` is useless, as you load `pxfonts`
- Also setting `\clubpenalty=10000` is useless, because LaTeX will restore a different value after the first `\section` command. If you really want that (and I discourage you from doing it) say

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \@clubpenalty=10000 \clubpenalty=10000
  \makeatother
  ```

Comment: Where do the magic `-6\baselineskip` stem from?

Comment: @mafp I just tried a couple of values.